# Problems with looping around my function?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, input, while-loop

I'm designing a guess game where i have to guess where's a ball within a list. The ball is represented by an 'O'. The idea is: if the player cant choose correctly the game restarts, if the player chooses correctly the game says "congrats" and stops.

```
from random import shuffle

def shuffle_list(mylist):
    shuffle(mylist)
    return mylist

mylist=['','O','']

def player_guess():
    
    guess=''
    while guess not in ['0','1','2']:
        guess= input("Pick a number: 0, 1, 2 ")
        
        return int(guess)

def check_guess(mylist,guess):
    if mylist[guess]== 'O':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def repeat():
# INITIAL LIST
    mylist=['','O','']
#SHUFFLE LIST
    mix_list= shuffle_list(mylist)
    print(mix_list)
#USER GUESS
    guess= player_guess()
    if guess not in ['0','1','2']: #si no esta en el rango repite
        repeat()
#CHECK GUESS
    check=check_guess(mix_list,guess)
    if check== False: #si no le achunta repite
        repeat()   
    else:
        print("congrats")
        exit()#exit the program

repeat()
```

The game restarts if you chosed wrong but it keeps going if you chosed correct.
Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Please next time include the [tag:python] when you are asking a python question

Comment: Does it print "congrats"?

Comment: Don't use recursion in place of a `while True:` loop. When you want to get out of the game, use `break`. And if they enter invalid input, use `continue` to go back to the beginning.

Comment: How do you know you're guessing correctly? Each time you call `repeat()` it shuffles the list again. So you might keep guessing wrong even if you try all 3 locations.

Comment: `return` ends the function (and therefore breaks any loop inside it). So, in your `player_guess` function, it doesn't matter which value is inputted, it will always return that value. You can unindent the return statement so it's outside the while loop.

Comment: Also, if the function `player_guess` ensures the player can only input values that are valid, there's no need to check that again. Just fix  `player_guess` and forget about that awkward recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use recursion to repeat an action. Instead you can use a `while` loop with a condition set to `True` and break it.

Also, because the function `player_guess` is supposed to ensure that the player can only input valid values

> ```
> if guess not in ['0','1','2']: #si no esta en el rango repite
>        repeat()
> ```

shouldn't be necessary. However `player_guess` doesn't work as intended because `return` ends the function (and therefore breaks any loop inside it). This can be fixed by unindenting the return statement outside the while loop.

Also, you define `mix_list` bur never use it anywhere. Because `shuffle` shuffles the list *in place* (i.e. it modifies the original list) `mix_list` and `mylist` end up referring to the same object.

And finally, `check_guess`:

```
def check_guess(mylist,guess):
    if mylist[guess]== 'O':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

is always returning the result of evaluating `mylist[guess] == 'O'`. So everything can be condensed in `return mylist[guess] == 'O'`.

All put together, your code would be something like this:

```
from random import shuffle

mylist = ['','O','']

def player_guess():
    guess = ''
    while guess not in ['0', '1', '2']:
        guess = input("Pick a number: 0, 1, 2 ")
    return int(guess)

def guess_game():
    while True:
        shuffle(mylist)  # shuffles the list in place
        guess = player_guess()
        if mylist[guess] == 'O':
            print("congrats")
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two big problems.

The first is:

The `player_guess` function returns int(guess), you then proceed to check `if guess not in ['0','1','2']`.

As we discussed before, `guess` is an integer and you are comparing it to strings.

You can fix this by simply changing:

```py
if guess not in ['0','1','2']
```

to

```py
if guess not in [0, 1, 2]
```

The second problem is also here:

```py
if guess not in ['0','1','2']: #si no esta en el rango repite
    repeat()
```

On this line, you are not terminating the existing function, so once the recursion of repeat has ended, it will go back to the first function call and keep running.

Instead, you could do:

```py
if guess not in ['0','1','2']: #si no esta en el rango repite
    repeat()
    return
```

Or even better, change it into a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement:

```
if guess not in ['0','1','2']: 
    repeat()
```

you are comparing the variable `guess` with string. Change `['0','1','2']` to `[0,1,2]` like this:

```
#USER GUESS
    guess= player_guess()
    if guess not in [0,1,2]: #si no esta en el rango repite
```